# connection to Rserve from RSclient over TLS fails 95% of the time

Tags: r, ssl, https, tls1.2, rserve

I am having an issue, where I connect to Rserv from RSclient and the connection doesn't work 95% of the time, when making a TLS connection. It literally fails most of the time and >sometimes< it just works.
however, when I make a connection without TLS, it works every time.
here's an unsuccessful connection:

```
con <- RS.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 4445, tls = TRUE)
RS.login(con, user = "myRserveUserName", password="myRservePW", authkey=RS.authkey(con))
rsc_abort: read error
Error in RS.authkey(con) : read error - could not obtain response header
```

meanwhile, in the RServe console I get this error:

```
Error: ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

I will just add that I am running latest R and library versions and openssl.
I would appreciate any ideas. thanks

EDIT: adding sessionInfo() output

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RSclient_0.7-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3
```

Comment: Could you provide `sessionInfo()` for client and server machines?

Comment: Does this also occur when client and server are on the same host?

Comment: @parasietje yes the server and client are on one box

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov edited main post

Comment: The purpose of this setup is to make a connection with a SAP HANA system. Since the original post, we got that one to work, by simply using a certificate chain instead of a single certificate. so technically the main problem has been fixed. BUT the connection from R to Rserve still doesn't work, which is curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised this bug report on github:
https://github.com/s-u/Rserve/issues/92

the developer has confirmed it was an issue with RSclient and he has fixed it.